# MySQL Server is not starting and not present in Services.msc

Tags: mysql, windows

Few months ago I installed MySQL Server 5.* for windows. But due to some dependencies I manually made the 'Auto Start' as 'Manual Start' for MySQL in the Services.msc Registry. After that I uninstalled that and installed XAMPP and worked on it till yesterday. Now I uninstalled XAMPP. 
I Installed MySQL in windows , "Server 5.6" and "Workbench 6.1". Now the MySQL is not present in the Services.msc registry. I cannot start it.

The following are the errors I get when i try to start them.

1. "Could not connect, server may not be running.   Can't connect to
   MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)"
2. 2014-08-07 10:32:56 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is depreca
   ted. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentati
   on for more details).
   2014-08-07 10:32:56 6304 [Warning] Can't create test file c:\Program Files\MySQL
   \MySQL Server 5.6\data\Raj.lower-test
   2014-08-07 10:32:56 6304 [Warning] Can't create test file c:\Program Files\MySQL
   \MySQL Server 5.6\data\Raj.lower-test

Please help me solve this error. I searched a lot on the Internet but was unsuccessful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

Did you created MySql instance ? 
Check in task manager that mysqld process is running. if you have windows 7 
**Open task manager click on process tab -> click on show all process -> check mysqld in list -> right click on mysqld -> go to service(s) or go to file location**

it may help you ..